# How to provide cloud-init user-data to hyper-v machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init

How to provide cloud-init user-data to hyper-v machine? Is That even possible?
I tried to build iso9660 image that contains only the user-data file and its label is cidata. The ubuntu server 20.04 gives me: stages.py[INFO]: Loaded datasource DataSourceNone - DataSourceNone